# Spring MVC make individual page accessible without login

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring MVC and I am trying to make an html page accesible without the need to login. My security xml configuration is as follows:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/err404.html" access="permitAll()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.html" access="permitAll()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/accesibleWithoutLogin.html" access="permitAll()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/assets/**" access="permitAll()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('AUTH_ADMIN')" />
    <form-login login-page="/login.html" 
                login-processing-url="/static/j_spring_security_check"
                authentication-success-handler-ref="authSuccessHandler"
                authentication-failure-url="/login.html?t=error" />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login.html?act=logout" />
</http>
```

with this configuration I can access accesibleWithoutLogin.html but all the back-end(ajax requests to spring mvc) functionality is lost.

How can this page be fully functinal without having to login?

Comment: Are ajax requests are accessing resources/urls that should be secured behind a login? If no, then you can add a "permitAll()" for those urls to the configuration. If yes, then those ajax requests belong on the /accessileWithoutLogin.html page.

Comment: The problem seems to be line : pattern="/**" access="hasRole('AUTH_ADMIN')". I managed to circumvent it for now by deleting the line and replacing it with:
    <intercept-url pattern="/page.html" access="hasRole('AUTH_ADMIN')" />
for every page in the app except the accesibleWithoutLogin.html. Not clean at all but it meets the requirements I've been given.